# What is the Manifest Digest in GitLab and how do I find out more information about the manifest?

Tags: gitlab, images

GitLab provides for a "Manifest Digest",

[image: Manifest Digest]

What exactly is the Manifest Digest, a digest of, and how do I get access to this manifest to see how it's different from other images..

---

*this question is a follow up to [What is the GitLab "Digest" on the container registry next to the images, why is different for two duplicated images](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17529/18965)*